# Matlab GUI sliders: Change position directly to clicked point

Tags: matlab, onclick, slider

Does any one know a way to change the behavior of Matlab sliders so that they move directly to the value you click on?

For instance, lets say a slider is initialized at zero (far left side). I'd like to able to click anywhere on the slider (including the far right side) and have the slider instantly move to that location. The way they normally work you'd have to click repeatedly to move the slider over to the right side one increment at a time, or hold down the right arrow.

I am running an experiment where subjects need to assign values for 420 sliders! It would speed things up a lot of each slider only required a single click.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you torturing your subjects or what? :-P

Comment: haha. What we want to do is have 7 slider responses to 70 stimuli. However, I'm afraid it's going to take way too long (we try to keep experiments no longer than 35 minutes in our lab), which is exactly why I'm trying to find a way to speed things up. We'll probably have to reduce the number of sliders and/or stimuli, but we're piloting to see how things go.